# How can I run Jupyter Dash app in offline mode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-dash, offline, jupyterdash

I haven’t got internet connection on my work machine, but I’d like to use dash. When I try to run my code with

```
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
```

I also get only white screen without any graphics or errors.
Here some simple code for example:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = JupyterDash('offline example')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', figure={'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2]}]})
])

app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode=“Inline”)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always run JupyterDash without an internet connection. So that's not the problem here. I rather think that you haven't installed all components you need to run plotly and JupyterDash properly. If you're able to run the latest versions, take a closer look on how to run all necessary installations [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/):

You should also take a look at what [this youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkOKkrKqI-k&ab_channel=CharmingData) has to offer on tips & tricks

It may also be the case that you for some reason are not able to launch your app **in** JupyterLab. You can check this by changing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode="Inline")
```

To:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode="external")
```

Which will fire up the Dash app in your default browser.